# exit.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `_exit' when using arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: gcc, arm

I'm new to the field of microcontrollers. I need to port an IDE which is compiling programs for AVR microcontrollers to compile programs for ARM microcontrollers. I have just replaced the compiler from AVR to ARM and added some options as told by someone.
The following is the command:

```
\ARM-GCC\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc -O0 -ffunction-sections -Wall -std=gnu99 -mfloat-abi=soft 
-Wa,-adhlns="$@.lst" -fmessage-length=0 -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -g3 -gdwarf-2 -Wl,
--gc-sections -o <Dir_name>\Build_Files\Blink_arm.cpp.elf  <Dir_name>\Build_Files\Blink_arm.cpp.o <Dir_name>\Build_Files\core.a 
-L<Dir_name>\Build_Files -lm
```

When I execute it I get the follwing error:

```
tools/arm-gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.6.2\libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): In function `exit':
exit.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `_exit'  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

May I get some help on what is this error and how can I solve it. And also I don't know what those options in the command line specify.

Comment: in your ARM libc (that is bundled with your compiler), the `exit()` function makes a call to `_exit()`, which isn't defined in any library. your compiler must be set up incorrectly, although you could perform a quick fix by defining `void _exit(int status)` yourself (NOTE: this won't work is your libc declares _exit() with a different signature. your `_exit()` could simply halt in an infinite loop like its AVR counterpart. fixing your GCC installation would be the recommendable option.

Comment: See: [newlib syscalls](https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#Syscalls); you need to implement these, if they are not implemented for your board.  Also, there can be issues with your code.  Newlib doesn't support everything;  See [Gatliff's newlib](http://www.billgatliff.com/newlib.html) overview.

Comment: I think the second link in the above comment is dead now. Archive version: https://web.archive.org/web/20130802225623/http://www.billgatliff.com/newlib.html

Answer (score 118):

This happens when compiling a file with `arm-none-eabi-gcc` in one machine/architecture to load it in an ARM target machine. Most probably you are not making use of semihosting, you want to retarget.

ARM® Compiler toolchain Version 4.1 indicates:

> Semihosting is a mechanism that enables code running on an ARM target to communicate and
>   use the Input/Output facilities on a host computer that is running a debugger.

From the toolchain's readme.txt (under folder `.../gcc-arm-none-eabi-VERSION/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi`):

> ** non-semihosting/retarget
>
> If you are using retarget, linking like:
>   $ arm-none-eabi-gcc --specs=nosys.specs $(OTHER_LINK_OPTIONS)

For me `--specs=nosys.specs` was enough ;)

Comment: I did a quick search for the ARM compiler documentation quoted above. I couldn't find docs as far back as 4.1, but the ["ARM Compiler Software Development Guide Version 5.06"](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0471/m/what-is-semihosting-/what-is-semihosting-?lang=en) seems to be its successor, and does include that definition of semihosting.

Answer (score 88):

Use `--specs=nosys.specs`:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --specs=nosys.specs $(OTHER_LINK_OPTIONS)
```

Reference:

- [ARM Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html)
- [GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/170926122/readme.txt)

Comment: Why `--specs=nosys.specs` is not specified by default?

Comment: If anyone reading this has enough rep for a 1-character edit, there's now an https version of the "ARM Options" URL.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem.
The solution was as follows:

- Add options `-ffreestanding -flto` into compiler call line.
- And add options `-flto -ffreestanding -nostdlib` into linker call line.

Comment: I think -f options are not allowed for the linker, right? Here is my shiny error
`arm-none-eabi-ld: -f may not be used without -shared`