# Makefile linking: undefined reference to _exit

Tags: makefile, arm, stm32

I have been trying to create a neatly-organized makefile project template utilizing the ARM mbed library. I have already solved a few of the problems ([see this post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106184/library-include-not-detecting-header-in-include-path) related to header file paths. However, now I am having problems with the linker. My goal is to have sources and headers in *src*, object files in *obj*, and the final binaries in either *debug* or *release*.

Here is the error I am getting...

```
make
arm-none-eabi-g++  -DTARGET_M4 -DMBED_BUILD_TIMESTAMP=1453683815.81 -DTOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM -DTOOLCHAIN_GCC -DTARGET_RTOS_M4_M7 -DTARGET_FF_MORPHO -DTARGET_CORTEX_M -D__FPU_PRESENT=1 -DTARGET_FF_ARDUINO -DTARGET_STM32F446RE -DTARGET_NUCLEO_F446RE -D__MBED__=1 -DTARGET_STM -DTARGET_STM32F4 -D__CORTEX_M4 -DARM_MATH_CM4 -std=c++98 -fno-rtti -I lib/ -I lib/mbed/ -I lib/mbed/TARGET_NUCLEO_F446RE/ -I lib/mbed/TARGET_NUCLEO_F446RE/TARGET_STM/ -I lib/mbed/TARGET_NUCLEO_F446RE/TARGET_STM/TARGET_STM32F4/ -I lib/mbed/TARGET_NUCLEO_F446RE/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/ -I lib/mbed/TARGET_NUCLEO_F446RE/TARGET_STM/TARGET_STM32F4/TARGET_NUCLEO_F446RE/ -o obj/main.o src/main.cc
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.1.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): In function `exit':
exit.c:(.text.exit+0x2c): undefined reference to `_exit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:54: obj/main.o] Error 1
```

This is my makefile. I have denoted where the problem(s) might be, but I am not sure.
    #Project parameters
    PROJECT = Nucleo_blink
    OBJECTS = obj/main.o
    DEST    = debug
    VPATH   = src lib $DEST
    TARGET  = NUCLEO_F446RE

```
#Compilation options
DEBUG = 1

#Tools
AS      = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-as
CC      = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-gcc
CXX     = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-g++
LD      = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-gcc
OBJCOPY = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-objcopy
OBJDUMP = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-objdump
SIZE    = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-size 

include $(TARGET).mk

CFLAGS = $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(CC_SYMBOLS) $(CPU) -c -g -fno-common -fmessage-length=0 -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fomit-frame-pointer -MMD -MP

ifeq ($(HARDFP),1)
        FLOAT_ABI = hard
else
        FLOAT_ABI = softfp
endif

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
        CFLAGS += -DDEBUG -O0
else
        CFLAGS += -DNDEBUG -Os
endif

#MY PROBLEM MAY BE HERE
LD_FLAGS = $(CPU) -Wl,--gc-sections --specs=nano.specs -Wl,--wrap,main -Wl,-Map=$(PROJECT).map,--cref
#`-u _printf_float -u _scanf_float` after -specs for floating point I/O

LD_SYS_LIBS = -lstdc++ -lsupc++ -lm -lc -lgcc -lnosys 

LIBRARIES = -lmbed 

.PHONY: all clean lst size

all: $(PROJECT).bin $(PROJECT).hex

clean:
    rm -f debug/* obj/* asm/* $(DEPS)

obj/%.o: %.c
        $(CC)  $(CC_FLAGS) $(CC_SYMBOLS) -std=c99 $(INCLUDE_PATHS) -o $@ $<

obj/%.o: %.cc
        $(CXX) $(CC_FLAGS) $(CC_SYMBOLS) -std=c++98 -fno-rtti $(INCLUDE_PATHS) -o $@ $<

obj/%.o: %.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CC_FLAGS) $(CC_SYMBOLS) -std=c++98 -fno-rtti $(INCLUDE_PATHS) -o $@ $<

obj/%.o: %.asm
        $(CC) $(CPU) -c -x assembler-with-cpp -o asm/$@ $<

#OR HERE
$(PROJECT).elf: $(OBJECTS) $(SYS_OBJECTS)
        $(LD) $(LD_FLAGS) -T$(LINKER_SCRIPT) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) -o $(DEST)/$@ $^ $(LIBRARIES) $(LD_SYS_LIBS) $(LIBRARIES) $(LD_SYS_LIBS)

$(PROJECT).bin: $(PROJECT).elf
        $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $< $@

$(PROJECT).hex: $(PROJECT).elf
        @$(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $< $@

$(PROJECT).lst: $(PROJECT).elf
        @$(OBJDUMP) -Sdh $< > $@

lst: $(PROJECT).lst

size: $(PROJECT).elf
        $(SIZE) $(PROJECT).elf

DEPS = $(OBJECTS:.o=.d) $(SYS_OBJECTS:.o=.d)
-include $(DEPS)
```

Before you ask, I have already tried changing `--specs=nano.specs` to `--specs=nosys.specs`. It does nothing. The strange part is that the linker settings above work fine for the automatically generated mbed makefile.

Here is the working makefile. It compiles without errors...

```
# This file was automagically generated by mbed.org. For more information, 
# see http://mbed.org/handbook/Exporting-to-GCC-ARM-Embedded

GCC_BIN = 
PROJECT = Nucleo_blink
OBJECTS = ./source/main.o 
SYS_OBJECTS = #Long list of object files
INCLUDE_PATHS = -I. -I./source -I./mbed -I./mbed/TARGET_NUCLEO_F446RE -I./mbed/TARGET_NUCLEO_F446RE/TARGET_STM -I./mbed/TARGET_NUCLEO_F446RE/TARGET_STM/TARGET_STM32F4 -I./mbed/TARGET_NUCLEO_F446RE/TARGET_STM/TARGET_STM32F4/TARGET_NUCLEO_F446RE -I./mbed/TARGET_NUCLEO_F446RE/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM 
LIBRARY_PATHS = -L./mbed/TARGET_NUCLEO_F446RE/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM 
LIBRARIES = -lmbed 
LINKER_SCRIPT = ./mbed/TARGET_NUCLEO_F446RE/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/STM32F446XE.ld

############################################################################### 
AS      = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-as
CC      = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-gcc
CPP     = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-g++
LD      = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-gcc
OBJCOPY = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-objcopy
OBJDUMP = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-objdump
SIZE    = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-size 

ifeq ($(HARDFP),1)
        FLOAT_ABI = hard
else
        FLOAT_ABI = softfp
endif


CPU = -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=$(FLOAT_ABI) 
CC_FLAGS = $(CPU) -c -g -fno-common -fmessage-length=0 -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fomit-frame-pointer -MMD -MP
CC_SYMBOLS = -DTARGET_M4 -DTARGET_FF_ARDUINO -DTOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM -DTOOLCHAIN_GCC -DTARGET_RTOS_M4_M7 -DTARGET_FF_MORPHO -DTARGET_LIKE_MBED -DTARGET_CORTEX_M -D__FPU_PRESENT=1 -DTARGET_LIKE_CORTEX_M4 -DTARGET_NUCLEO_F446RE -D__MBED__=1 -DTARGET_STM -DMBED_BUILD_TIMESTAMP=1468213384.59 -DTARGET_STM32F446RE -DTARGET_STM32F4 -D__CORTEX_M4 -DARM_MATH_CM4 

#My makefile above copies these two lines
LD_FLAGS = $(CPU) -Wl,--gc-sections --specs=nano.specs -u _printf_float -u _scanf_float -Wl,--wrap,main -Wl,-Map=$(PROJECT).map,--cref
LD_SYS_LIBS = -lstdc++ -lsupc++ -lm -lc -lgcc -lnosys


ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
CC_FLAGS += -DDEBUG -O0
else
CC_FLAGS += -DNDEBUG -Os
endif

.PHONY: all clean lst size

all: $(PROJECT).bin $(PROJECT).hex size


clean:
        rm -f $(PROJECT).bin $(PROJECT).elf $(PROJECT).hex $(PROJECT).map $(PROJECT).lst $(OBJECTS) $(DEPS)


.asm.o:
        $(CC) $(CPU) -c -x assembler-with-cpp -o $@ $<
.s.o:
        $(CC) $(CPU) -c -x assembler-with-cpp -o $@ $<
.S.o:
        $(CC) $(CPU) -c -x assembler-with-cpp -o $@ $<

.c.o:
        $(CC)  $(CC_FLAGS) $(CC_SYMBOLS) -std=gnu99   $(INCLUDE_PATHS) -o $@ $<

.cpp.o:
        $(CPP) $(CC_FLAGS) $(CC_SYMBOLS) -std=gnu++98 -fno-rtti $(INCLUDE_PATHS) -o $@ $<



$(PROJECT).elf: $(OBJECTS) $(SYS_OBJECTS)
        $(LD) $(LD_FLAGS) -T$(LINKER_SCRIPT) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) -o $@ $^ -Wl,--start-group $(LIBRARIES) $(LD_SYS_LIBS) -Wl,--end-group


$(PROJECT).bin: $(PROJECT).elf
        $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $< $@

$(PROJECT).hex: $(PROJECT).elf
        @$(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $< $@

$(PROJECT).lst: $(PROJECT).elf
        @$(OBJDUMP) -Sdh $< > $@

lst: $(PROJECT).lst

size: $(PROJECT).elf
        $(SIZE) $(PROJECT).elf

DEPS = $(OBJECTS:.o=.d) $(SYS_OBJECTS:.o=.d)
-include $(DEPS)
```

I think my problem is some sort of path error...
- The `_exit` symbol may be defined, but inaccessible by *main.o*
- There may be some major error in the makefile I'm missing
- Something totally different?

Feel free to comment any suggested changes to this question.

**EDIT: All I had to do to fix the error was change `CFLAGS` to `CCFLAGS`. The answer I marked as the solution explained what was happening, and a potential way to fix it. Although I didn't need to use the suggested solution, the explanation of why it wasn't working is useful, and the information provided by both answers is useful.**

Comment: Where is $CC_FLAGS coming from in your makefile? You define $CFLAGS but never reference that AFAICS. You're trying to use a separate link step, but according to the error apparently not passing `-c` at the compile step.

Comment: @Notlikethat That was part of my problem. Fixing it resulted in some other unrelated errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The _exit symbol may be defined, but inaccessible by main.o - There may be some major error in the makefile I'm missing - Something totally different?

This happens when a call to a standard library method indirectly has a dependency on `exit()`. Often from automatically generated exception unwind code that's supposed to abort your process on exit, which obviously has different semantics in a bare metal application. The division-by-zero floating point exception is one such example. `-fno-exceptions` does not help with this.

You can of course supply a do-nothing `exit()` handler but your code would be smaller if the exception unwind code didn't get inserted in the first place.

I discovered by examining the generated assembler that you can replace the exception handlers with do-nothing versions like this in a compilation unit:

```
extern "C" void __wrap___aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0() {} 
extern "C" void __wrap___aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1() {} 
extern "C" void __wrap___aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr2() {}
```

and then link those in as replacements at link time with these additional linker arguments.

```
-Wl,-wrap,__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0,
-Wl,-wrap,__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1
-Wl,-wrap,__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr2
```

Another benefit is that your code should shrink as a result. You may even want to insert your own implementations that reset the MCU.

Answer (score 14):

Adding `--specs=nosys.specs` to your linker options may also solve this issue.

You can see exactly what this does by looking at the *nosys.specs* file which will be somewhere in your compiler directory.

See also: [exit.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `_exit' when using arm-none-eabi-gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419782/exit-c-text0x18-undefined-reference-to-exit-when-using-arm-none-eabi-gcc)

Answer (score 7):

`_exit` is a system call, as well as some other functions you probably will need later. When you compile a binary for (for example) Linux, these calls are serviced by the operating system. In bare-metal embedded project you need to define these functions by yourself. The common way is to create a file called `syscalls.c` or something like that and put all needed system calls there. Take a look at example of such file, rapidly found by google: https://github.com/bjornfor/stm32-test/blob/master/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Lib_V1.1.1/syscalls.c

As a bonus, if you properly implement `_read` and `_write` to work with UART, you will get a serial console capable to do formatted IO via `printf` and `scanf` .

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I could see your advice as being useful, but it was not the solution in my particular case. I think mbed takes care of the system calls.

Answer (score 1):

For me it took  both `-fno-exceptions` and `--specs=nosys.specs` in compiler flags.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you use stdlib. System cal `exit(int)` calls in-system function `_exit(int)`.

For me decision was applying `-nostdlib` option because I wasn't going to use `stdlib`.

Thanks, [UserHuman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10172050/user-human), https://stackoverflow.com/a/51657692/8313090