# global scoped variables in c++ not properly initialized

Tags: c++, c++14, stm32, stm32cubemx, truestudio

I ported my code from stm32f072 to stm32f105. Since then I have an issue with global variables, it seems they don't get initialized. I use Atollic TrueStudio and their compile and build tools. For the new platform I tried converting the existing "eclipse" project and also to create a new one from CubeMx.

I got a Hardfault when accessing a global object. The "workaround" was moving the `new` statement in the accessing function. The debugger showed that even when having the new statement the global var was `0x00`.

I also use an std::queue which has an `size()` of `0xffffffe7` when not inserted anything yet, which let me believe this also comes from a missing initialization.

I want to solve the issue, not move all init in the beginning of the main function as a workaround.

My code looks something like this:

```
#include <queue>

std::queue<Telegram> telegram_in_fifo;
Port *port1 = new IoPort(/* some args */);

void some_function() { // tried calling from Interrupt or from main 
    // port1 is 0x00 here
    port1 = new IoPort(/* some args */);
    // now port1 has proper address and accessing internal data works without hardfaults

    uint64_t size = telegram_in_fifo.size(); // this is 0xffffffe7
    if(size <= fifo_max) {
        telegram_in_fifo.push(telegram);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `some_function` from? This might be a case of *static initialisation order fiasco*.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that `some_function()` is called from an initializer of some global variable in a different source file. The order of initialization of global variables from different source files is unspecified.

Comment: please try to prepare a [mcve]. With the code you posted alone it isnt possible to get a size of `0xffffffe7` for the queue

Comment: some_function is called in an Interrupt or from main

Comment: @Fritz Might the interrupt be called before main?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43650493/understanding-c-runtime-environment-arm-where-to-start  It's likely that the C Runtime is not initializing your variables, probably due to a toolchain mismatch or some other tools issue.  Go through your build environment with a tine toothed comb to look for inconsistencies.

Comment: @john no, since I enable the interrupt in main and send explicitly later. I now have to investigate further about the static init order fiasco

Comment: @Fritz The better technique is to use a lazy evaluated [_Singleton_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern) class, which contains all the necessary `static` variables  as encapsulated class member variables (non static).