# vram_functions.o: in function `rtc_init_language_struct': nvram_functions.c:(.text+0x4a28): undefined reference to `__ctype_ptr__'

Tags: c, arm

I am working with arm-none-eabi-gcc on Ubuntu 20.04 version.
My code repo already contains arm tools, but those are 2012 tools.
When I did make(the file which contains compile commands), I got the arm-none-eabi-gcc not found error.
Resolved this error by downloading the latest arm tools and replacing tool files.
Later got an undefined reference for the '__exit' error, which I resolved by checking the post at [exit.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `_exit' when using arm-none-eabi-gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419782/exit-c-text0x18-undefined-reference-to-exit-when-using-arm-none-eabi-gcc)
Currently am facing a new error

tools/arm-2012.09/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ../Debug/obj/nvram_functions.o: in function `rtc_init_language_struct': nvram_functions.c:(.text+0x4a28): undefined reference to` **ctype_ptr**'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [makefile:299: elf] Error 1

Please help me resolve this issue. Unable to find a solution in other posts

Answer (score 1):

Compilers and their support libraries tend to come in pairs - I wouldn't expect this to work if you just replaced the compiler binary but not the support libraries.

Compiled binaries built with one compiler version, or linked against a specific C library binary, are not guaranteed to be compatible with those compiled with a different version of the same compiler or C library.

Comment: I have copied all required binaries as well.

Comment: Can someone help me on this. I kind of stuck with this. Unable to identify which libraries were missing here.

Comment: Again, this is normally a sign that you have mismatched objects/libraries built with different versions of the compiler and/or C library. Rather than patching bits of an existing compiler install, compile the whole project (including dependencies) with a clean install of the same compiler. Make sure your C library also comes from the same compiler install.